# Generalizing code that does the same thing with different function calls and properties

Tags: c#

I have a block of code that uses the property of some object as an indexer to call a function on another object in an array. Less convoluted explanation:

```
// Random example class
class Foo 
{
    private string message;
    public Foo(string msg) { this.message = msg; }
    public void Speak() { Console.WriteLine(message); }
}

// In another class elsewhere
private static Foo[] foos = 
{
    new Foo("hello"),
    new Foo("sup")
};

void doStuff(int id) 
{
    Bar b = database.GetBar(id); // Get object
    if (b.SomeIntProperty < foos.Length) 
    { 
        // Use object property as index
        foos[b.SomeIntProperty].Speak(); // Call this exact Foo function
        b.SomeIntProperty++; // Increment object property
        database.UpdateBar(b); // Save object
    }
}

// In yet another class, with another Foo[] array called 'stuff'
void doOtherStuff(int id) 
{
    Person p = database.GetPerson(id);  // Get object
    if (p.SomeOtherIntProperty < stuff.Length) 
    { 
        // Use object property as index
        stuff[p.SomeOtherIntProperty].Speak(); // Call this exact Foo function
        p.SomeOtherIntProperty++; // Increment object property
        database.UpdatePerson(p); // Save object
    }
}
```

As can be seen by the comments, the exact same sequence of things are done--just that different object types and properties are used. I tried to strip things out in to a `FooList` class but got stuck on how to handle the mentioned differences. I thought about using generics, but the name of the property used isn't always the same (even with another `Bar` or `Person` object). How can I go about this?

Comment: Have all the desired classes implement an `ISomeIntPropertyProvider` interface that exposes a `SomeIntProperty`.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield How do I expose different properties of the same class at different times though? Would I basically have to make a new mini-class implementing that interface for every different property or is there a better way around it?